# Find 'distance from the edge' of a numpy array

Tags: numpy, scipy

I have a numpy array with `1`s & `0`s (or bools if that's easier)

I would like to find the distance from each `1` its closest 'edge' (an edge is where a `1` meets a `0`).

Toy example:

Original array:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Result:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 2, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

If possible, I'd like to use the 'cityblock' distance, but that's lower priority

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach using [`binary_erosion`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_erosion.html) & [`cdist(..'cityblock')`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) -

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_erosion
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

def dist_from_edge(img):
    I = binary_erosion(img) # Interior mask
    C = img - I             # Contour mask
    out = C.astype(int)     # Setup o/p and assign cityblock distances
    out[I] = cdist(np.argwhere(C), np.argwhere(I), 'cityblock').min(0) + 1
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [188]: img.astype(int)
Out[188]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])

In [189]: dist_from_edge(img)
Out[189]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Here's an input, output on a human blob -

[image] [image]

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yup, awesome approaches we got, all with scipy!

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way you can do this with [`scipy.ndimage.distance_transform_cdt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.distance_transform_cdt.html) (or [`scipy.ndimage.distance_transform_bf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.distance_transform_bf.html)):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import distance_transform_cdt


def distance_from_edge(x):
    x = np.pad(x, 1, mode='constant')
    dist = distance_transform_cdt(x, metric='taxicab')
    return dist[1:-1, 1:-1]
```

For example:

```
In [327]: a
Out[327]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1]])

In [328]: distance_from_edge(a)
Out[328]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 2, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=int32)

In [329]: x
Out[329]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])

In [330]: distance_from_edge(x)
Out[330]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

If you don't pad the array with zeros, you get the distance to the nearest 0 *in the array*:

```
In [335]: distance_transform_cdt(a, metric='taxicab')
Out[335]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 2, 2],
       [0, 1, 2, 3]], dtype=int32)

In [336]: distance_transform_cdt(x, metric='taxicab')
Out[336]: 
array([[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
       [3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2]], dtype=int32)
```

---

Here a different method that uses [`scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion.html).  I wrote this before I discovered the distance transform function.  I'm sure there are much more efficient methods, but this should work reasonably well for images that are not too big.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import binary_erosion


def distance_from_edge(x):
    dist = np.zeros_like(x, dtype=int)
    while np.count_nonzero(x) > 0:
        dist += x  # Assumes x is an array of 0s and 1s, or bools.
        x = binary_erosion(x)
    return dist
```

For example,

```
In [291]: a
Out[291]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1]])

In [292]: distance_from_edge(a)
Out[292]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 2, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1]])

In [293]: x
Out[293]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])

In [294]: distance_from_edge(x)
Out[294]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```